# What is the sensor width of an iPhone 11? I need it for motion tracking

Tags: camera, tracking, motion-capture

I recently filmed a video with the iPhone 11 and I'm having trouble finding the sensor width needed for motion tracking.

I have found online it uses a 1/2.55 sensor width which blender actually offers a preset for 1/2.5 widths but what if want it more accurate? Will it affect my motion track results?

I have found the focal length: 13mm (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Thanks for any help :))

Comment: Hello :). Respectfully, I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Blender, but about iPhone Specs.

Comment: By the way - you can manually type in the sensor size if you want it precise :)

Answer (score 3):

Found more specifications at https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_11-9848.php

The focal length for a wide video is 26mm, 1/2.55 sensor width and pixel size 1.4nm.

I have found: https://www.vision-doctor.com/en/camera-calculations/sensor-diagonal-sensor-ratio.html. I simply put in the video's pixel width and height (3840 x 2160) and the pixel size (1.4nm). It gave a more accurate sensor width than the preset in Blender: **5.38mm**.

Hopefully, this helps someone.